# PHP returns fatal error instead of error number when connecting to MySQL under XAMPP

Tags: php, mysqli

My current computer has XAMPP installed and I have used it successfully to test PHP programs for some years.  I recently bought a new computer and have installed the latest version of XAMPP on it, as well as transferring a number of PHP application programs to it.  When trying to connect to a database, I use the following logic:

```
<?php
function dbConnect() {`
@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'centr120_genuser', 'Baroque73!', 'centr120_cmp' );
$test = mysqli_connect_errno();
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'pract458_genuser', 'Gunjur64!', 'pract458_cmp' );
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      $test = mysqli_connect_errno();
      echo "Error # ".$test."<br/>";
      echo 'Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again later.';
      exit;
    }
  }
return $db;
}
?>
```

This logic is used by all my applications on a number of different host servers to connect to a database, and it always works fine.  First, a connection to the client's live database is attempted.  If this fails because that database is not available or some other error occurs, then an attempt to connect to the test database is made.

On the new computer, on executing the first connection attempt, I get the message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'centr120_genuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmp\connectdb.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cmp\connectdb.php(3): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'centr120_genuse...', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'centr120_cmp') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\cmp\index.php(17): dbConnect() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmp\connectdb.php on line 3

For some reason, a fatal error occurs on the first connection attempt, which means that the test for the error number ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) never gets executed.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Even if this is just a private machine, you should consider changing your passwords now they are public.

Comment: The question is, WHY you're using the following logic.

Answer (score 2):

It must be because you installed PHP >= 8.1

> [mysqli_report](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php): As of PHP 8.1.0, the default setting is MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT. Previously, it was MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF.

I suggest you rewrite your code with try-catch statements:

```
function dbConnect() {
    try {
        return new mysqli('localhost', 'centr120_genuser', 'Baroque73!', 'centr120_cmp');
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception) {}

    return new mysqli('localhost', 'pract458_genuser', 'Gunjur64!', 'pract458_cmp' );
}
```

This way, PHP will return the first connection if it works, and otherwise will try to create the second one.

Note that printing something like "Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again later." is a bad practice. Your code should be able to handle any fatal error, not only the database connection. And the error message must be generic, without any particular details.

Comment: Your first point about the PHP version number put me on the right track.  However, your suggested solution did not work on 8.1, so I installed version 8.0.30 instead, and it still did not work; my logic did work .  Now I will have to modify your solution to work properly on 8.1 in the expectation that many hosting providers will be moving to 8.1 if they have not already done so.  Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score -2):

In new versions of `PHP`, when a `mysqli` connection fails, a `Fatal Error` will be raised.

This prevents running unexpected codes after failed queries after a failed connection; for example when an `insert` query has been executed, you might want to create a flag file or something else. If with any reason your DB connection fails, then how to sure that you have a plan to catch the error and don't create that important flag file?

because of this, `PHP` stops executing the script with raising a `Fatal Error`. the porblem should be solved if you use `try-catch` blocks instead of checking `mysqli_connect_errorno()` function.

try to run this script instead:

```
<?php
function dbConnect() {
  $db = null;
  try {
    # first connection
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'centr120_genuser', 'Baroque73!', 'centr120_cmp');
  } catch(mysqli_sql_exception $ex) {
    try {
      # second connection
      $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'pract458_genuser', 'Gunjur64!', 'pract458_cmp');
    } catch(mysqli_sql_exception $ex2) {
      echo "Error # ".mysqli_connect_errno()."<br/>";
      echo 'Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again later.';
      exit;
    }
  }
  return $db;
}
?>
```

[More details about `try-catch` structure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

### IMPORTANT SECURITY WARNING:

Please note that you just published your private passwords and now, you **MUST** to change them even you think nobody can access your virtual server or anything else.

Comment: You should never do anything like echo "Error # ".mysqli_connect_errno()."<br/>"; Also, you shouldn't use try-catch blocks instead of checking mysqli_connect_errorno() function. Actually, neither should be used.

Comment: Because your answer is incorrect and features bad practices. You may read about proper error reporting here https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting